# I am trying to check that If email already exist in databse or not or not in database but my code throws error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-web-api

This is the error I am getting in my console;

**GET http://localhost:1089/api/Employee/EmailAlreadyExist?%22some@abc.com%22 404 (Not Found)**

This my ajax code where I am sending the user email while creating a new user, and I want this method to let me know if the email already exist in database or not;

```
function CheckAvailability() {
    var email = $("#officialemail").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'http://localhost:1089/api/Employee/EmailAlreadyExist',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(email),
        success: function (response) {
            var message = $("#message");
            if (response) {
                //Email available.
                message.css("color", "green");
                message.html("Email is available");
            }
            else {
                //Email not available.
                message.css("color", "red");
                message.html("Email is NOT available");
            }
        }
    });
}

function ClearMessage() {
    $("#message").html("");
};
```

and I am passing this entire function in another fucntion in which I am passing the email parameter in attempt of creating a new user along with all of the other parameters with their values;

```
$('.empOfficialDetails').click(function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    CheckAvailability()

    var data = new Object();
    data.UserName = $('#username').val();
    data.UPassword = $('#userpass').val();
    data.OfficialEmailAddress = $('#officialemail').val();
    data.Departments = $('#departments :selected').text();
    data.Designation = $('#designation :selected').text();
    data.RoleID = $('#role').val();
    data.Role = $('#role :selected').text();
    data.ReportToID = $('#reportToID').val();
    data.ReportTo = $('#reportTo :selected').text();
    data.JoiningDate = $('#joindate').val();
    data.IsAdmin = $('#isAdmin :selected').val() ? 1 : 0;
    data.IsActive = $('#isActive :selected').val() ? 1 : 0;
    data.IsPermanent = $('#isPermanent :selected').val() ? 1 : 0;
    data.DateofPermanancy = $('#permanantdate').val();
    data.HiredbyReference = $('#hiredbyRef :selected').val() ? 1 : 0;
    data.HiredbyReferenceName = $('#refePersonName').val();
    data.BasicSalary = $('#basicSalary').val();
    data.CurrentPicURL = $('.picture').val();

    if (data.UserName && data.UPassword && data.OfficialEmailAddress && data.Departments && data.Designation && data.Role && data.IsAdmin && data.IsPermanent) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:1089/api/Employee/EmpOfficialDetails',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#dvRoomsLoader").show();
            },
            complete: function () {
                $("#dvRoomsLoader").hide();
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var ID = parseInt(data);
                if (ID > 0) {
                    //var id = data;
                    $(".HiddenID").val(data);
                    //var id = $(".HiddenID").val();
                    $('#official').css('display', 'block');
                    $('#official').html("Employees Official details added successfully...!");
                    $('#official').fadeOut(25000);
                    $("#dvRoomsLoader").show();

                    $('.empOfficialDetails').html("Update &nbsp; <i class='fa fa-angle-right rotate-icon'></i>");
                }
                else {
                    $('#official').find("alert alert-success").addClass("alert alert-danger").remove("alert alert-success");
                }
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                alert("There was an error while submitting employee data");
                alert('Error' + ex.responseXML);
                alert('Error' + ex.responseText);
                alert('Error' + ex.responseJSON);
                alert('Error' + ex.readyState);
                alert('Error' + ex.statusText);
            }
        });
        
    }
    return false;

});
```

and in my controller I am using an inline query to check for similar email in my database;

```
[Route("api/Employee/EmailALreadyExist")]
    [HttpGet]
    public bool EmailAlreadyExist(string email)
    {
        string retval;
        var con = DB.getDatabaseConnection();
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        string query = "IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Employee WHERE OfficialEmailAddress = @OfficialEmailAddress)";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OfficialEmailAddress", email);

        email = emp.OfficialEmailAddress;
        SqlDataReader rdr = com.ExecuteReader();
        if (rdr.HasRows)
        {
            retval = "true";
        }
        else
        {
            retval = "false";
        }
        return Convert.ToBoolean(retval);
    }
```

all of the help I get is highly appreciated and sugesttions for making this code better are all warmly welcomed

thank you

Comment: Did you test your `EmailAlreadyExist(` method directly?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Yes but I don't know why I am getting the error all the time I run it, and I am new to all of this so all of this is really confusing for me

Comment: `EmailAlreadyExist` vs `EmailALreadyExist` - they are not the same. So you are calling a route that does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your url

`http://localhost:1089/api/Employee/EmailAlreadyExist?%22some@abc.com%22`

it looks like you aren't passing email parameter correctly.

You can pass it like

`http://localhost:1089/api/Employee/EmailAlreadyExist?email=some@abc.com`

or change your route a bit to support your url

`[Route("api/Employee/EmailAlreadyExist/{email}")]`

Answer (score 1):

I can see that there is a typo in the route. The L in EmailALreadyExist is capitalized. But you are calling it with a lowercase letter.

Also, I am seeing a missing semicolon in the Ajax code, check that out too.

Comment: On the `CheckAvailability()` line, that is, right? (Missing ";")

Comment: Yes there. Sorry for omitting that. I didn't really check your code very far, just followed the trace of your error till I hit the first issue, and then stopped. All followup problems will appear once that's solved.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your code uses a GET method that can't have a body. So it had to append an URL parameter to it. In ASP.NET it should be named. But your method has not named parameters. So it is not found. Add the parameter name to your payload (name "email"). to your JSON - replace in your JS function `CheckAvailability` `data: JSON.stringify(email),` with `data: JSON.stringify({email: email}),`. Then jQuery should call for `api/Employee/EmailALreadyExist?email=....` that will match `public bool EmailAlreadyExist(string email)`.
2. It is better to use a POST method to hide the email in the request body. Then your original code could have a C# smaller update:
   `public bool EmailAlreadyExist([FromBody]string email)`. It will map the single parameter from the body to the C# `email` variable.
3. There is a point to separate your logic from the controller. "Thin controller" could validate parameters, a service will contain your "business logic".

Comment: _"EmailALreadyExist"_ => I'd actually fix the typo in the route.